SOLR Search Crashes Website with Large Result Sets
I'm encountering an issue with my website's SOLR-based search functionality. The search works well for smaller datasets, but when the result set exceeds 4000 elements, the webpage crashes, throwing an error 500 that seems to originate from SOLR.
I'm seeking suggestions on how to scale up my system to handle larger volumes of data and queries effectively. Here are some details about my setup:
SOLR version: 8.9.0
Website technology stack: PHP/Drupal framework
Any advice or suggestions on optimizing SOLR performance, scaling up the system, or troubleshooting the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I've checked the SOLR logs, but they don't indicate any specific problems. Additionally, I've attempted to address the issue by increasing the open file limit and the maximum number of processes, but this hasn't resolved the problem.

A 500 error should have a full error message behind it somewhere, likely in a log file (e.g. Apache, PHP, or similar). That should give you a clue as to the exact nature of the problem. That should be found and analysed before jumping to conclusions about the most appropriate solution. If there seems to be no error, check that everything in the application stack is adequately configured to log all errors to a file.

By default Solr paginates the results (e.g. it gives the first 10 out of the 4000 results). Typically 4000 results is not a lot of documents for Solr. I would check your rows parameter to see how large is the page size in your system.
